# Idiomatic way to build a custom structure from XML zipper in Clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

Say, I'm parsing an RSS feed and want to extract a subset of information from it.

```
(def feed (-> "http://..." clojure.zip/xml-zip clojure.xml/parse))
```

I can get links and titles separately:

```
(xml-> feed :channel :item :link text)
(xml-> feed :channel :item :title text)
```

However I can't figure out the way to extract them at the same time without traversing the zipper more than once, e.g.

```
(let [feed (-> "http://..." clojure.zip/xml-zip clojure.xml/parse)]
    (zipmap 
        (xml-> feed :channel :item :link text)
        (xml-> feed :channel :item :title text)))
```

...or a variation of thereof, involving mapping multiple sequences to a function that incrementally builds a map with, say, `assoc`.

Not only I have to traverse the sequence multiple times, the sequences also have separate states, so elements must be "aligned", so to speak. That is, in a more complex case than RSS, a sub-element may be missing in particular element, making one of sequences shorter by one (there are no gaps). So the result may actually be incorrect.

Is there a better way or is it, in fact, *the* way you do it in Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
(reduce (fn [h item] 
          (assoc h (xml1-> item :title text) 
                   (xml1-> item :link text))) 
        {} (xml-> feed :channel :item))
```